# PDO prepare error

Tags: php, mysql

```
public function connect(){
        /*connect to data base change to PDO, for securely*/
        try{
        $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=system', 'root', '' );
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die('this won\'t work');
        }
    }

    public function insert($table, $fields, $values){
        $fields = implode(", ", $fields);
        $values = implode("','", $values);
        try{
        /*what have i done wrong here??*/
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("INSERT INTO $table(ID, $fields) VALUES ('', '$values')");
        $stmt->execute();
        return TRUE;
        }catch(PDOException $j){
            die("Could not send data");
        }
    }
}
```

error :Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in.the prepare is there but is null ?

what i done wrong here?

Comment: you need to change `$connection` to `$this->connection` in your `connect` function ... all instances

Comment: Where are you making the `$connection` variable? Because it seems to be a local variable inside the function now.

Comment: side note, you are not using `PDO` correctly!!! this is not secure!

Comment: how will it be secure ??

Comment: alternatively you could return $connection from your connect() method and call it inside the insert method with $con=$this->connect(); this would mean that you won't connect until you are actually going to perform a transaction.  This isn't the best way to do this, you are effectively building an abstraction class over an abstraction class.  You should just extend PDO and make a custom child class that handles your needs.

Comment: sorry i am confuse , can you point out or give me a sample where i done wrong ? i am not sure i understand all.

Answer (score 2):

You are not storing your connection to the object. So in your next method the connection object is lost. Try this:

```
  try{
    $this->connection = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=system', 'root', '' );
    $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die('this won\'t work');
    }
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: done thank you  , i was so careless i miss add the first , $this->connection = new PDO